# MySQL Order Results by Closest Number to Given Number

Tags: php, mysql

I'm struggling with a query to select results that are closest to a number. This is for the site www.soulmate.dating

Essentially I have a query that includes the GEO location of each member (besides other data) and I want the results to be Ordered by those closest to the selected GEO location.

This is the Query:

```
select distance from users;
```

Note: $this->locationGEO is set by the user (they can pick a place) and it could be 41546

When the results come back if I just order by Distance its not the closed number to value in $this->locationGEO - eg: 41546.

How can I run a query that returns results closed to a number - say 41546.

Rather then order highest to lowest etc.

thx

Comment: `order by abs(distance - 41546) asc`. Also, `where` in your query makes it syntactically incorrect. It is not needed.

Answer (score 4):

Your query can be something like:

```
select distance from users order by abs(distance - 41546) asc;
```

`abs` is necessary so that the distance is compared on both sides of *41546* (user input).